# R Ridge Regression: Choosing best lambda

Tags: r, ridge-regression

I am doing ridge regression with Mass package and stuck with the problem trying to find the best lambda.
I know that it should look somehow like thi

```
lm.ridge(y ~x1 + x2+ x3...data = data, lambda=seq(0,1,.1))
help <- lm.ridge(y ~x1 + x2+ x3...data = data, lambda=seq(0,1,.1))
plot(help)
select(help)
```

select(help) gives me the following output:

```
modified HKB estimator is 13.50453 
modified L-W estimator is 85.33649 
smallest value of GCV  at 1
```

But what is my best lambda the? The smallest value for GCV?
Also I don't understand what values I should pick for

```
lambda=seq(0,1,.1)
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Sometimes I have better results by optimizing the effective AIC.  This is implemented in the R `rms` package `ols` and `pentrace` functions.  This may be more stable than cross-validation.  More may be found here: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/FHHandouts/iscb98.pdf

Answer (score 3):

(Changing a comment to an answer.) Yes, you want the lambda that minimizes GCV. MASS's lm.ridge doesn't choose a default lambda sequence for you. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686067/default-lambda-sequence-in-glmnet-for-cross-validation) which talks about good default choices for lambda. Also, I'd suggest using cv.glmnet with alpha = 0 (meaning ridge penalty) from glmnet package which will do this cross validation with some good lambdas for you. Use glmnetUtils package in addition if you like a formula interface like lm.ridge. See ?cv.glmnet after installing glmnet (and glmnetUtils, if you want).